# Boot stuck at "A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories"

Tags: linux, boot, ubuntu-18.04, tmp

I think something generated millions of files or folders in my /tmp on Ubuntu 18.04, as I'm unable to run `ls /tmp` or even `rm -rf /tmp/*`. So I tried rebooting, but now my machine's stuck at the step:

```
A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories
```

I let it run for 10 hours, and it's still going, so it's likely swapping to disk and will never complete. What do I do? How do I clear my /tmp folder if I can't even boot the system?

Edit: I appended "systemd.debug-shell=1 systemd.show_status=false" so I could get to a shell. Then I killed the `systemd-tmpfiles` process and then ran `mkdir /empty; time rsync -a --delete /empty/ /tmp/` to do a fast delete as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files). However, after 30 minutes, it's still running.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [boot in single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub), move the tmp folder, create a new clean one, set the permissions and reboot. Then you can do whatever needs to be done with the old tmp.

in the single user session do:

```
mv /tmp /old.tmp
mkdir /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

and reboot.

Comment: Even in single-user mode, it still hangs at the "Create Volatile Files and Directories" step.

Comment: I used my boot flags, and then your method worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Cerin Could you specify what boot flags do you mean? See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209478/boot-stuck-at-ubuntu-logo?noredirect=1#comment2030672_1209478.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem but the single user mode didn't help. So I entered using the recovery mode(changing the ro flag with rw to be able to modify the file system, I did that doing some steps similar to the linked answer in Eduardo's answer). Once on recovery mode I just run the 'root' option and did what Eduardo said.

Comment: Same problem but I couldn't get into a sheel as the message "create volatile.." still appeared even in single user or recovery mode. What I did was change ro to rw on grub and append `init=/bin/bash` so it forces a shell.

Comment: before run `mv` command, you should get the write permission by `mount / -o rw,remount`.